# Cognito - Can't add cognito:groups for an user

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am currently working on AWS with Cognito for user management,

I would like to be able to import a CSV with my users to add to the project. With the basic information I can successfully add a user.

However I will want to **add a user** with an **associated group** (already existing) directly **in the CSV** and I have [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5kvx.png).

I think the attribute should not be allowed in the header,

Can we add a group to the user when importing the CSV?

If not, what can I do to fix it?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

here's the code of the CSV file i used:

```
name,given_name,family_name,middle_name,nickname,preferred_username,profile,picture,website,email,email_verified,gender,birthdate,zoneinfo,locale,phone_number,phone_number_verified,address,updated_at,cognito:mfa_enabled,cognito:username,cognito:groups
Test,,TEST,,,,,,,test@test.fr,false,, 01/01/2000,,,+3360000000,true, 51 rue Térus,,false,test,directeur
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all there is no such header like **cognito:groups** for Cognito User import. You can get an dummy file with all supported headers from AWS console (Cognito User Import page, click on *Download CSV Header* button) or via AWS Cognito API Call. Since I'm using python my call looks like that:

```
cognito = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
headers = cognito.get_csv_header(UserPoolId=COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID)['CSVHeader']
```

You cannot add your own headers and supply values for these headers (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-using-import-tool-csv-header.html).

Unfortunately, right now (20211207) there is no way how to force Cognito User Import to create groups and\or put users inside these groups - it just imports users.

As a solution I created a lambda function, that saves not only user list (in a Cognito Import compartible format) but a user-group structure in a CSV file as well (username, group_name headers). Then after user list is imported, I run a small script that opens a second CSV file and adds users to the groups one by one using *admin_add_user_to_group* method (I higly recommend to catch the following exception cognito_client.exceptions.UserNotFoundException).